# Using DLLs in Python that return values to pointers

Tags: python, pointers, dll, reference, ctypes

I'm using Python to connect to an old database and I'm using the EHLLAPI DLL file to talk to my terminal emulator. EHLLAPI uses a single call-point interface where everything is done through the hllApi function. The function only takes pointers as parameters. I have no problem sending data to the emulator.

Problem is values are returned to the pointers in the second through fourth parameters, not as the return value of the function. If you look at the last 3 lines of code you can see that to pull a string from the screen I have to set up a second string buffer, create a pointer, pass that to hllapi, decode whatever's returned back, and then place that into my original string buffer.

This just seems messy and inefficient. Is there a cleaner more efficient way to do this?

```
from ctypes import *

hllDll = WinDLL ("Ehlapi32.DLL")
hllApiProto = WINFUNCTYPE (c_int, c_void_p, c_void_p, c_void_p, c_void_p)  
hllApiParams = (1, "p1", 0), (1, "p2", 0), (1, "p3",0), (1, "p4",0)
hllApi = hllApiProto (("hllapi", hllDll), hllApiParams)

sBuf = ""
hllRc = 0

def hllGetString(nRow, nCol, sLen):
    global sBuf
    
    sBuf2 = c_char_p (sBuf.encode('ascii')) # <----------- Is there a better way to do this? ---
    hllApi (byref (c_int (8)), sBuf2, byref (c_int (sLen)), byref (c_int (hllRc))) # <----------
    sBuf = sBuf2.value[0:sLen].decode('ascii') # <----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What is the C prototype of the hllapi function in the DLL?  What are the required inputs and expected outputs?   Having an actual example would help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a little guessing without a sample prototype or implementation of the actual function, so I made one.  Provide your own if I guessed wrong and I'll update the answer:

**test.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

__declspec(dllexport)
int __stdcall hllapi(void* p1, void* p2, void* p3, void* p4) {
    printf("p1 = %d\n", *(int*)p1); // input (command code?)
    int len = *(int*)p3;            // length of p2 buffer
    printf("p3 = %d\n", len);
    memset(p2,'A',len);             // Fill length of buffer
    *(int*)p4 = 1;                  // return code output parameter?
    return 0;                       // not used?
}
```

You can't get away with the casting if the actual function takes `void*`, at least not if the parameter types changed based on usage.  I'm guessing that the first parameter is a command code that affects the remaining three parameters, so you have ot use `void*` for that flexibility.  The last parameter seems like an output parameter, so it needs storage that survives after the call to return that value.  Note that `byref(c_int(hllRc))` creates a ctypes integer of that value that only exists for that line of code and is deallocated (at least in CPython) immediately after that line of code.

Also to match a `char*` type of parameter you still need the `.encode()` and `.decode()` sandwich to make a `bytes` string if you want to start and end with a Unicode (`str`) string.

**test.py**

```py
from ctypes import *

hllDll = WinDLL ('./test')
hllApi = hllDll.hllapi
hllApi.argtypes = c_void_p, c_void_p, c_void_p, c_void_p
hllApi.restype = c_int

def hllGetString(nRow, nCol, sLen):
    buf = create_string_buffer(sLen)  # allocate storage for the buffer
    hllRc = c_int() # allocate storage for return code (Rc?)
    hllApi(byref(c_int(8)), buf, byref(c_int(sLen)), byref(hllRc))
    return hllRc.value, buf.raw.decode('ascii')

print(hllGetString(1, 2, 10))
```

Output:

```
p1 = 8
p3 = 10
(1, 'AAAAAAAAAA')
```